# Fixed sticky header jumps after onscroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I've got the following code for a [sticky header](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/website-terms-of-use.html), but I can't make the scroll a smooth transition. The fixed header jumps after a single scroll.

**The basic html:**

```
<div class="headerWrapper">
    <div id="top-nav-wrapper"></div>
        <div class="header"></div>
</div>
   <div class="headerPlaceholder"></div>
        <div class="mainContent">
          *page content goes here*
         </div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
    body {
      background: #EEE;
    }

    #top-nav-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #B8B8B8;
      z-index: 2001;
      background: #EEE;
    }

    .header {
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 90px;
      z-index: 2000;
      background: #EEE;
      height: 90px;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #C4C4C4;
    }

.headerPlaceholder {
    height:90px;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
}


body.fixed .header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
body.fixed .headerPlaceholder {
    display: block;
}
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var start = $('.header').offset().top;

    $.event.add(window, "scroll", function () {
        var p = $(window).scrollTop();
        if( p > start ) {
            $('body').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

To make it a smooth transition, there might need to be a slight delay and fadein/out effect, if anyone could help or suggest an alternative.

**[This is the page to test](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/website-terms-of-use.html)**

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGsX4/)

Comment: you should add a class "fixed" instead of hammering your DOM with direct style changes every time a scroll event fires. the class will be added only once if needed, else, removed.

Comment: also, i don't see your header "jumps". it's very smooth.

please use `getBoundingClientRect().top` inside your scroll callback to check if the headers needs to start moving or not. your current method of testing the offset is wrong.

Comment: what do you want to happen? when I scroll down, the header is stick to the top, it works perfectly in your link. I don't see ANY jump. it works great.

Comment: it's because it must not change from "absolute" or what ever, to "fixed". leave it always absolute, and change the "top" to match your scroll point, on scroll event

Comment: @uname12 What browser, Version and OS are you using? I took a look and your fiddle works just like the awwward page in firefox 24.3.0 on widows 7. They both fail horribly on IE v8(I know but I can't update it) windows 7. I don't really blame the sites as IE 8 is very old and this version is so very limited compared to future ones.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `animate()` method for smoother transition. Using it, animate the div according to your needs.

Comment: don't use animate, it's not for that. bad practice.